# Store multiple variables as a single hex string

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am looking for a way to store a few variables in one variable so I can output a string.  For example, I have variables:

```
int flow_val = "128";
int numb_val = "104";
int size_val = "256";
```

I can put them together using `$display` like this:

```
$display("32'h%0h%0h_%4h", flow_val, numb_val, size_val);
```

to print out:

```
32'h8068_0100
```

Is there a way to get that output and put it into a variable such as `hex_val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sformatf` can be used.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 21.3.3 *Formatting data to a string*.

```
module tb;

int flow_val = 128;
int numb_val = 104;
int size_val = 256;
string hex_val;

initial begin
    hex_val = $sformatf("32'h%0h%0h_%4h", flow_val, numb_val, size_val);
    $display(hex_val);
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
32'h8068_0100
```